# virtual method vs non virtual method in the same class

Tags: c++, methods, polymorphism, virtual

In the following code, we have two classes in each of them two methods: one is virtual and the second non virtual. I don't understand what really happens when I run this code. In which case and with which function (1,2,3) the system use the vitual or non virtual function? For all the cases, I wrote in comments what I obtained when the code ran. I'm a little confusing ... Thanks in advance

```cpp
class cFather {
    public:
            void print( )       { cout<<” 1) cFather\n”;}
    virtual void print( ) const { cout<<” 2) cFather\n”};
};

class cSon : public cFather {
    public:
    virtual void print( )       { cout<<” 3) der\n”; }
    void print( ) const { cout<<” 4) der\n”; }
};

void function1 (const cFather& o)
{
    o.print( );
}

void function2 (const cFather o)
{
    o.print( ); 
}

void function3(cFather o)
{
    o.print( ); 
}
```

A)

```
void main ( )
{   cFather o;
function3(o);    }
// 1)   CFather
```

B)

```
void main ( )
{   cSon t;
function1(t);    }
// 4) der
```

C)

```
void main ( )
{   cFather * o;
cSon t;
o = &t;
o->print( );    }
// 1)   cFather
```

D)

```
void main ( )
{   cFather o;
function2(o);    }
// 2)   cFather
```

Comment: That is not the "only difference"; one is const, the other isn't.

Comment: Which behaviour, specifically, do you not understand?

Comment: You're right I modified it!!

Comment: I don't understand why for example in the case A, we use the non virtual method and why not the virtual one?

Comment: Because `o` is non-const.

Comment: ‏@OliverCharlesworth Ok I didn't notice it was relevant ... Thanks a lot for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual methods are dynamically resolved at runtime **only** if you invoke it via a pointer or a reference. In all other cases, the function to be called will be resolved statically at compile time.

You should understand how virtual methods works. Simply speaking, the compiler store in your object **a pointer to function for every virtual method** of that class. When you call a virtual method via a pointer o a reference, the function pointed by the corresponding pointer in your object will be invoked. So, the call will be **resolved at runtime**.

So, only `function1` can dynamically call the *correct* method, because it's the only one that has its argument passed by reference and not by value.

Case "D" is not resolving at runtime wich method has to be called; it's just picking the second method because it is invoked on a `const` object. It would behave the same even if it was not virtual.

Comment: I know it, but why in the case D, the system use the virtual one for example?

Comment: @Laura : it doesn't use the virtual one because it's `virtual`, but because it's `const`.

Comment: Thanks for your responses... You helped me a lot